# Unity download image from Firebase database

Tags: unity

I am currently trying to download an image using Google Firebase.

The database stores a URL to an image on Firebase storage, Unity pulls the URL from the DB and uses Unity WWW to download it. However the texture shows up as a red question mark texture.

If I use a http URL from another website however it works, is Unity able to download from https addresses?

This downloads the URL from Firebase and stores it in the data_url variable:

```
void DownloadViaURL()
{
    Debug.Log("Called DownloadViaURL");
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
   .GetReference("test_image")
   .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
       Debug.Log("Default Instance entered");
       if (task.IsFaulted)
       {
           Debug.Log("Error retrieving data from server");
       }
       else if (task.IsCompleted)
       {
           DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

           string data_URL = snapshot.GetValue(true).ToString();

           //Start coroutine to download image
           StartCoroutine(AccessURL(data_URL));
       }
   });
}
```

This uses Unity WWW to download from the URL:

```
IEnumerator AccessURL(string url)
{


    //Debug.Log("Accessing texture URL in database");
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        r.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
        Debug.Log("Texture URL: " + www.url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, read permission was disabled in the Firebase storage settings.